# How to select the Autocomplete value using Cucumber Step definition

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Here is my code. If I type S letter it displays 3 results and I want to select only one value . can someone help me how to select only one value using Cucumber step definition.

```
<form id="Form" name="ReportForm" action="/Test/Report.action" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label class="formlabel"><font size="2pt">Name
                        Name</font></label></td>
            <td>
                  <select dojoType="struts:ComboBox" id="RportName" forceValidOption="true" autoComplete="true" dropdownWidth="300" size="1" keyName="selected" visibleDownArrow="false" searchLimit="10"
 >
    <option value="1">SharePoint</option>
    <option value="2">JavaCode</option>
    <option value="3">Cloud Services</option>
    <option value="4">SQL Database</option>
    <option value="5">Oracle</option>
    <option value="6">System</option>
  </select>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">djConfig.searchIds.push("Name");</script>
```

Comment: Cucumber itself is just a test framework, it does not interact with browsers. You need to explain what gem you are using for driving the browser (ex Watir, Capybara, Selenium-Webdriver, etc.) and what you have tried. Creating a page that reproduces the problem will also greatly help (ie what JavaScript library is turning the select list into an autocomplete)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using capybara with cucumber and assuming that you know how to call a helper method from a step definition and your select box has an id

```
module FormSH

  def select_second_option(id)
    second_option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[2]"
    second_option = find(:xpath, second_option_xpath).text
    select(second_option, :from => id)
  end
end
World FormSH
```

Then from your step def

```
select_second_option('RportName')
```

should be enough to get you going.